# Struggling with SQL

Tags: sql

I have two table in the same database: hlstats_Events_Connects and hlstats_PlayerUniqueIds.

In the hlstats_Events_Connects I have a value I wish to get, however the ID it's related to I need to get from the data in another table, using the "uniqueId" that I have. Example:

```
**hlstats_Events_Connects**

playerId     eventTime
----------------------
8           2013-04-05 05:44:14


**hlstats_PlayerUniqueIds**

playerId     uniqueId
---------------------
8            0:0:84901
```

So I have the "uniqueId" as a variable, and I want to say, get the playerId of the persons uniqueId, then get the eventTime from what the playerId is.  Currently I have something along the lines of the below, but can't figure out the Where clause.

```
SELECT c.eventTime, c.playerId, u.uniqueId, u.playerId
FROM  c.hlstats_Events_Connects, u.hlstats_PlayerUniqueIds
WHERE ...?
```

Comment: If you want to pass uniqueid and get eventtime then : `SELECT c.eventTime, c.playerId, u.uniqueId, u.playerId
FROM  c.hlstats_Events_Connects, u.hlstats_PlayerUniqueIds
WHERE c.playerId = u.playerId and u.uniqueId = '0:0:84901'`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are just missing the `JOIN`.  You will join the tables on the `playerId` column:

```
SELECT c.eventTime, c.playerId, u.uniqueId, u.playerId
FROM  c.hlstats_Events_Connects c
INNER JOIN u.hlstats_PlayerUniqueIds u
  ON c.playerId = u.playerId
```

Note, I updated the query to use ANSI JOIN syntax, in this case an `INNER JOIN`. This is standard SQL syntax, instead of commas between the tables and the join in the `WHERE`

Answer (score 1):

Use `JOIN` like this

```
SELECT c.eventTime, c.playerId, u.uniqueId, u.playerId
FROM  c.hlstats_Events_Connects, u.hlstats_PlayerUniqueIds
WHERE c.playerId = u.playerId
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add prefixes to table names, instead those should be specified after table name, and also you can just join on `playerId` column (if those are large tables, I'd suggest adding an index to those columns.)

```
SELECT
    c.eventTime, c.playerId, u.uniqueId, u.playerId
FROM
    hlstats_Events_Connects c,
    hlstats_PlayerUniqueIds u
WHERE
    u.uniqueId = "0:0:84901" and
    u.playerId = c.playerId
```